# how to write a recursive program using c language?

Tags: c, recursion

I want to write a C program that read any five int input like A B C D E

and output

```
A-B, A-C, A-D, A-E

B-C, B-D, B-E

C-D, C-E

D-E
```

The `-` is to do the minus operator, using as short code as you can.

So I don't want to do for loop iteration.

```
int i,j,a[5]={'\0'};
scanf("%d%d%d%d%d",&a[0],&a[1],&a[2],&a[3],&a[4]);

for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
    for(int j=i+1;j<5;j++)
        printf("%d\n",a[i]-a[j]);
```

Comment: I don't think you'll get much shorter than that in C.

Comment: @immibis +1. C is not a language designed for that. With some functional language, the recursion method may be shorter, not here.

Comment: @immibis The question is not about whether or not the recursive version will be shorter or not, but how to write an as short as possible recursive version.

Comment: Sounds like a problem for http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/... Since professional programmers do not write "as short code as possible" but rather as readable/efficient code as possible.

Comment: Anyway, what have you written and what is the specific problem? This code is not recursive. This is not a "give me the code" site.

Answer (score 0):

Try this logic:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int func(int *a, int i, int j)
{
    if (j == 4)
        return 0;
    int tmp = 0;
    while(j != i)
    {
        int tmp2 = 0;
        tmp2 = a[j]-a[tmp+j+1];
        printf("%d\n", tmp2);
        i--;
        tmp++;
    }
    printf("\n");   
    func(a, 4, j+1);
}

int main()
{
    int arr[5]={'\0'};
    int i;
    int j = 0;
    for(i=0; i<5;i++)
    {
        scanf("%d",&arr[i]);
    }

    func(arr, i-1, j);
}
```

I have tried to avoid use of loop, same program is done using Recursion.

Below here also list output of program,

```
Input: Enter 5 number 1 2 3 4 5

Output : -1 -2 -3 -4    -1 -2 -3    -1 -2    -1
```

Comment: Thanks for the [free fish](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/give_a_man_a_fish_and_you_feed_him_for_a_day;_teach_a_man_to_fish_and_you_feed_him_for_a_lifetime). I'll come back tomorrow for more, make sure to have it ready. Salmon this time. [GJ making SO a worse site by encouraging code beggars!]

Answer (score 0):

For use only recursion you can do like this

```
#include<stdio.h>
int Recursion1(int *a1, int i, int j)
{
    if(j <= 4)
    {
        printf("%d\n", a1[i] - a1[j]);
        Recursion1( a1, i, j+1);
    }
    return 0;   
}
int Recursion(int *a1, int i, int j)
{

    if ( i <= 3 && j <= 4) 
    {
        Recursion1(a1, i, j);
        Recursion(a1, i + 1, j + 1);
    }
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    int a[5];

    printf("Enter five integer Value = ");
    scanf("%d %d %d %d %d", &a[0], &a[1], &a[2], &a[3], &a[4]);
    printf("Output is:\n");
    Recursion(a, 0, 1);
}
```

Output of Code is:

```
Enter five integer Value = 1
2
3
4
5
Output is:
-1
-2
-3
-4
-1
-2
-3
-1
-2
-1
```

Comment: Thanks for the [free fish](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/give_a_man_a_fish_and_you_feed_him_for_a_day;_teach_a_man_to_fish_and_you_feed_him_for_a_lifetime). I'll come back tomorrow for more, make sure to have it ready. Salmon this time. [GJ making SO a worse site by encouraging code beggars!]

Answer (score 0):

try this logic: This generate result that you want using recursion.

```
     #include<stdio.h>
     void recursion(int* array,int i,int j,int size)
     {
            if(i < size-1)
            {
                   if(j < size )
                   {
                        printf("%d\t",(array[i]-array[j]));
                        j++;
                        recursion(array,i,j,size);
                   }
                   else{
                         printf("\n");
                         i++;
                         j=i+1;
                         recursion(array,i,j,size);
                   }
            }
     }

    int main()
    {
       int i=0,j=i+1;
       int array[5]={2,3,4,7,8};
       recursion(array,i,j,5);
       return 0;
    }
```

Output :

```
-1  -2  -5  -6  
-1  -4  -5  
-3  -4  
-1
```

Comment: Thanks for the [free fish](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/give_a_man_a_fish_and_you_feed_him_for_a_day;_teach_a_man_to_fish_and_you_feed_him_for_a_lifetime). I'll come back tomorrow for more, make sure to have it ready. Salmon this time. [GJ making SO a worse site by encouraging code beggars!]

Answer (score 0):

To solve this recursively, first you have to think about the the problem in terms of the problem itself.

The list (array) consists of a *head* and a *tail*.

```
1 2 3 4 5
^ ^
H T
```

or

```
Head: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
Tail: 2, 3, 4, 5
```

**To output a result:**

Take the first element of the head of the list and subtract the first element of the tail of the list from it. Output the result.

**To output the first row:**

You then have a solution for how to output a result which you can re-use to output the other values on the row.  Just call the routine again with the same head but with the tail stepped one element further along.

```
1 2 3 4 5
^   ^
H   T
```

or

```
Head: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
Tail: 3, 4, 5
```

Recurse until there's no tail left. Then output a newline, because we know the row is finished.

**To output the other rows:**

Re-use the solution for doing the first row, but with the shorter list you get by stepping one element further along with the head.

```
1 2 3 4 5
  ^ ^
  H T
```

or

```
Head: 2, 3, 4, 5
Tail: 3, 4, 5
```

... and do all that until we can't any more, because the list doesn't have enough elements for a tail any longer.

In code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void doit(int *head, int headlen, int *tail, int taillen)
{
    if (taillen > 0) {
        printf("%d ", head[0] - tail[0]);
        doit(head, headlen, tail + 1, taillen - 1);
    }
    else {
        putchar('\n');

        if (headlen > 2) {
            doit(head + 1, headlen - 1, head + 2, headlen - 2);
        }
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    const int nelem = 10;
    int array[] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};

    doit(array, nelem, array + 1, nelem - 1);

    return 0;
}
```

Running it:

```
$ ./a.out
-1 -2 -3 -4 -5 -6 -7 -8 -9
-1 -2 -3 -4 -5 -6 -7 -8
-1 -2 -3 -4 -5 -6 -7
-1 -2 -3 -4 -5 -6
-1 -2 -3 -4 -5
-1 -2 -3 -4
-1 -2 -3
-1 -2
-1
```

Comment: Thanks for the [free fish](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/give_a_man_a_fish_and_you_feed_him_for_a_day;_teach_a_man_to_fish_and_you_feed_him_for_a_lifetime). I'll come back tomorrow for more, make sure to have it ready. Salmon this time. [GJ making SO a worse site by encouraging code beggars!]

Comment: @Lundin I usually give hints, but I thought that if I'll give a complete answer, the OP will have a hard time not using it. It will be a deviation from his usual performance, and cheating will be suspected.